# Cannot read property 'min' of undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs.i try to create simple page by using some tutorial.One page is for user input html and another one javascript for if else statement.I keep receive error in console as "Cannot read property 'min' of undefined".
index.html

```
<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
<div class="container">     
                <div class="row price-form-row" ng-if="!addListing">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Min Price</span>
                    <select name="minPrice" id="minPrice" [ng-model]="priceInfo.min" class="form-control">
                      <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                      <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                      <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
              </select>
                  </div>          
                <span class="input-group-addon">Max Price</span>
                    <select name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" ng-model="priceInfo.max" class="form-control">
                      <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                      <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                      <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
                     </select>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-4" 
        ng-repeat="crib in cribs | cribsFilter:priceInfo | orderBy: '-id'">          
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> {{crib.price | currency}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> {{crib.address}} 
                <span class="label label-primary label-sm">{{crib.type}}</span></div>             
 </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/cribsFilter.js"></script>
</html>
```

cribsFiler.js

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .filter('cribsFilter', function() {
    return function(listings, priceInfo) {
    var filtered = [];
    var min = priceInfo.min;
    var max = priceInfo.max;
     angular.forEach(listings, function(listing) {
      if(listing.price >= min && listing.price <= max) {
      filtered.push(listing);
                }
            });
       return filtered;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this changes:

```
ng-repeat="crib in cribs | cribsFilter:priceInfo.min:priceInfo.max | orderBy: '-id'"
```

and

```
.module('ngCribs').filter('cribsFilter', function() {
        return function(listings, min, max) {
        var filtered = [];
```

So the result code:

```
<div class="container">     
            <div class="row price-form-row" ng-if="!addListing">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Min Price</span>
                <select name="minPrice" id="minPrice" [ng-model]="priceInfo.min" class="form-control">
                  <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                  <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                  <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
          </select>
              </div>          
            <span class="input-group-addon">Max Price</span>
                <select name="maxPrice" id="maxPrice" ng-model="priceInfo.max" class="form-control">
                  <option value="100000">$100,000</option>
                  <option value="200000">$200,000</option>
                  <option value="300000">$300,000</option>
                 </select>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4" 
    ng-repeat="crib in cribs | cribsFilter:priceInfo.min:priceInfo.max | orderBy: '-id'">          
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> {{crib.price | currency}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> {{crib.address}} 
  <span class="label label-primary label-sm">{{crib.type}}</span></div>             
</div>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs').filter('cribsFilter', function() {
    return function(listings, min, max) {
    var filtered = [];
     angular.forEach(listings, function(listing) {
      if(listing.price >= min && listing.price <= max) {
      filtered.push(listing);
                }
            });
       return filtered;
        }
    });
```

Now you should not receive an error
Plunker: http://run.plnkr.co/l5oe6uLyfP4fpPJA/